# Writing 2 similar queries as one query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

In the following query below In my first join I compare the first 3 characters of a identifier to a prefix table, in my second join the remaining characters are put against a datacode table, then the datacode is validated in another table.

Then I filter by specific transaction types and processes and a date range.

In my second query I'm simple filtering by identifier codes that begin with Q and checking if the second character is numeric, then i'm filtering by the exact same filters as the upper query.

This query grabs what I need, however I'm trying to re-write the query in a manner which I will not have to repeat the filters from the upper query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.TrackID), 
    t1.CreatedDTS, t1.ITEMode, t1.ProcessName, t1.PID, 
    t4.State, SUBSTRING(t1.ProviderNumber,1,10), 
    t1.ISA06, t1.ISA08
FROM 
    PSVEngine.dbo.MessageZoe t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    SKU.dbo.CommonPref t2 ON SUBSTRING(t1.PID,1,3) = t2.Prefix
INNER JOIN 
    SKU.dbo.PIDS t3 ON SUBSTRING(t1.PID, 4, 9) = t3.PIDInfo
INNER JOIN 
    SKU.dbo.PidInfo t4 ON t3.UID = t4.UID
WHERE
    t1.CreatedDTS BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00' AND '2016-05-01 00:01'
    AND (t1.ProcessName IN ('Falcon','Zepplin') OR t1.ProcessName LIKE 'BKR%')
    AND (SUBSTRING(t1.[InfoType], 1, 3) = '340' or SUBSTRING(t1.[InfoType], 1, 3) = '345')

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT(t1.TrackID), 
    t1.CreatedDTS, t1.ITEMode, t1.ProcessName,   
    t1.PID, null, SUBSTRING(t1.ProviderNumber, 1, 10), 
    t1.ISA06, t1.ISA08
FROM
    PSVEngine.dbo.MessageZoe t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    t1.CreatedDTS BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00' AND '2016-05-01 00:01'
    AND (t1.ProcessName IN ('Falcon','Zepplin') OR t1.ProcessName LIKE 'BKR%')
    AND (SUBSTRING(t1.[TransactionType], 1, 3) = '340' or SUBSTRING(t1.[TransactionType], 1, 3) = '345')
    AND **t1.PID like 'Q%' and Isnumeric(SUBSTRING(t1.PID,2,1)) = 1**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables and set them in one place, like this:

```
declare @dateIni, @dateEnd datetime

set @dateIni = '2016-04-01 00:00'
set @dateEnd = '2016-05-01 00:01'
WHERE
    t1.CreatedDTS BETWEEN @dateIni AND @dateEnd
    AND (t1.ProcessName IN ('Falcon','Zepplin') OR t1.ProcessName LIKE 'BKR%')
    AND (SUBSTRING(t1.[InfoType], 1, 3) = '340' or SUBSTRING(t1.[InfoType], 1, 3) = '345')
```

Create variables for each filter value and replace in both queries. Then you can change filters in one place.

Comment: Functions and adds maintainability, but execution speed triple the time. Queries are 20+ minutes long.

Comment: Are you using the rigth data type?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( t1.trackid ), 
               t1.createddts, 
               t1.itemode, 
               t1.processname, 
               t1.pid, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN t1.pid LIKE 'q%' 
                      AND Isnumeric(Substring(t1.pid, 2, 1)) = 1 THEN NULL 
                 ELSE t4.state 
               END [state], 
               Substring(t1.providernumber, 1, 10), 
               t1.isa06, 
               t1.isa08 
FROM   psvengine.dbo.messagezoe t1 WITH (nolock) 
       INNER JOIN sku.dbo.commonpref t2 
               ON Substring(t1.pid, 1, 3) = t2.prefix 
       INNER JOIN sku.dbo.pids t3 
               ON Substring(t1.pid, 4, 9) = t3.pidinfo 
       LEFT JOIN sku.dbo.pidinfo t4 
              ON t3.uid = t4.uid 
WHERE  t1.createddts BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00' AND '2016-05-01 00:01' 
       AND ( t1.processname IN ( 'Falcon', 'Zepplin' ) 
              OR t1.processname LIKE 'BKR%' ) 
       AND ( Substring(t1.[infotype], 1, 3) = '340' 
              OR Substring(t1.[infotype], 1, 3) = '345' ) 
       AND ( ( t1.pid LIKE 'Q%' 
               AND Isnumeric(Substring(t1.pid, 2, 1)) = 1 ) 
              OR NOT ( t4.state IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: Doesn't pick up the records that start with Q and with the second character being numeric.